# Adding a unique ID to haml list item

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, haml, rspec-rails

I had the following line of code:

```
%li= link_to "Home", main_app.root_path
```

I now wish to include an ID for automation testing purposes to the minibar item but am unsure how to go about this, I have tried the following:

```
%li(id = "minibar_home")= link_to "Home", main_app.root_path
```

But the ID does not seem to be added when inspecting this through firebug or view source. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%li{:id => "minibar_home"}= link_to "Home", main_app.root_path
```

Or

```
%li#minibar_home= link_to "Home", main_app.root_path
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%li#minibar_home= link_to "Home", main_app.root_path
```